# Bootstrap col-md-3 sticky sidebar not functioning as expected

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I'm attempting to create a sticky sidebar within a Bootstrap col-md-3 column, but I'm having trouble getting the sticky functionality to work. I want the sidebar to stick to the top of the page as I scroll down the main content in col-md-9.

Here's the structure of my HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-start">
                <div class="sticky">
                    <div id="progressBarContainer">
                        <div id="progressBar" style="height: 88.9566px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <ul id="headingContainer">
                        <li data-heading-id="" class="active-heading">Heading 1</li>
                        <li data-heading-id="">Heading 2</li>
                        <!-- more list items -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <!-- Main content here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; /* Adjust this value if you want some space between the top of the viewport and the sticky element */
    z-index: 1020; /* Ensure it's above other content */
}
```

The .col-md-3 column is as tall as the .col-md-9 main content column, so there is content to scroll through. Despite this, the sticky sidebar isn't functioning as expected—it doesn't stick to the top on scroll.

Things I've checked/confirmed:

The DOCTYPE is set to .
No parent elements have overflow hidden or auto that could affect sticky behavior.
The sidebar content is less than the height of the viewport.
Tested in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox to ensure it's not a browser compatibility issue.

Can anyone spot what I might be missing or suggest a solution to get the sticky sidebar functioning correctly?

Here is the link to the live page.
https://thesalesforcerecruiter.com/blog/i-lost-my-job-6-things-to-do-before-you-job-hunt-part-1/

Comment: I can't quite get which container are you trying to make scrollable. In your code there is nothing set to scrollable, so the header is sticked relative to whatever parent container of your `container` class that is a scrolling container.

Comment: Also, the `col-md-3` will be placed at the left of `col-md-9` main content, not on top of it.

Comment: The sticky aspect is set to the .sticky. Ive read multiple jsfiddles where they have done the same and still i dont get that outcome.